# Saving To Documents Directory On iOS Intermittently Works / Fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nserror, uigraphicscontext

Is there any reason why writing and saving a PDF file to the Documents directory in an iOS application would only be intermittently successful? In my app I am created a PDF from an array of UIViews, accessing the Documents folder and storing the file in there.

I would estimate that this works 80% of the time. The other 20% of the time the PDF gets created (I also email it to myself which works) but it never actually get written to the Documents folder.

In the case of failure, I can email myself the PDF so I know it gets created. When I inspect the Documents folder in a file explorer it's empty. When I log out the contents of it it is also empty. I'm using the following code to create the PDF and export to Documents.

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

-(void)createPDFfromUIViews:(NSArray *)views saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename andTag:(NSInteger)tag
{
    // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    UIView *view1 = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, view1.bounds, nil);
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData
    for (UIView *view in views)
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        [view.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
    }

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // Get the path to the documents directory and append the filename of the PDF
    NSString *path = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory].path stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

    NSLog (@"DOCUMENTS DIRECTORY : %@", [self applicationDocumentsDirectory].path);
    NSLog (@"DOCUMENTS DIRECTORY WITH FILE PATH : %@", path);

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [pdfData writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingWithoutOverwriting error:&error];

    if (!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error writing PDF: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else
    {
        if (tag == 1)
        {
            NSLog(@"PDF Saved With Name %@", aFilename);
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
        else if (tag == 2)
        {
            [self checkAccountAndComposeEmailWithAttachmentData:pdfData andSubject:aFilename];
        }
    }

}
```

UPDATE: Code amended to include NSError. The error given is "The operation couldnt be completed. (Cocoa Error 4.)

UPDATE 2: Amended the code to include Apple's recommended method of grabbing the Documents directory. Also added in a number of logs to show that I am getting correct Directory / File Path - both are showing the Documents folder or the Documents/File Name as expected. Still returns `NSFileNoSuchFileError` as an error every time.

Comment: have you thought about putting a delay between once the PDF gets created and gets saved to your documents dir? Use a NSTimer to create a slight delay of 0.5 secs. Though technically your code is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should be writing with the API that allows you to pass an error pointer in

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path options:(NSDataWritingOptions)mask error:(NSError **)errorPtr
```

Then, you can inspect the `NSError` if it does not write properly, and act intelligently with this info.

```
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success = [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"Error writing: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

The specific error you have is a [NSFileNoSuchFileError](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html), a clue that perhaps there are spaces or some other non-supported character in the file path, amongst other reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Returns the following error: Error writing PDF: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)

Comment: That's NSFileNoSuchFileError: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html

Comment: I have seen this thrown on Insufficient disk space, amongst other reasons

Comment: well, the error is now being shown every time on simulator. Can't get my head around this one.

Comment: Can you give some example filenames? Perhaps there is a problem with spaces in the title.

Comment: The issue was indeed with the filenames. I was saving a filename with NAME_DATE.pdf (David_Smith_23/12/2013.pdf as an example). It believed that each '/' in the filename was a new directory. Ive replaced the / with a . and it works perfectly. Add as an answer and ill accept as best? Thanks

Comment: glad you solved it. I updated the answer to include this bit.